# Multiple bindings for same control

Tags: silverlight

I have a `ChildWindow` that has a `Listbox`. I have an enum for checking which table I want to load. I am basically reusing this child window to load many different tables from my `Entity` model via a `CollectionViewSource`. I am using the `ItemTemplate` and cannot bind simply to the `Text` property due to the dynamic field name of the various tables. I used to just set the `DisplayMemberPath` or set the `Text` via binding when using one table. How do I achieve this with `Binding` inside of the `ItemTemplate`? Can I make a property in code-behind and then just set that property, then bind to this property. I am not sure what the syntax would be for this kind of binding and not sure how to search for it. Thanks...

VS 2010, Silverlight 5.0

Comment: Are you using WCF data services or RIA services?

Comment: WCF RIA Services link.